# How to display degrees symbol without encoding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I get the degrees symbol to display correctly on a web page created with Asp.Net MVC without encoding it? The following HTML code will display �C using VS 2017:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>°C</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the cshtml file in question saved as UTF-8? (Files -> Advanced save options)?

Comment: try &deg; (or the equivalent &#176;).

Comment: you can also use <p>23 &#8451;</p>
<p>25 &#x2103;</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by ensuring that the source file in Visual Studio 2017 was saved with the correct UTF-8 encoding.

To do this, first select Save As from the File menu. Then select the "Save with Encoding..." option in the Save dialog:

[image: Save with Encoding...]

Then select the UTF-8 encoding:

[image: Advanced Save Options]